# update data in warm indices in opensearch

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch

Are there any strategies to update data in warm indices in opensearch ?

I am trying to update data in opensearch. The following is happening :

I used this query :

```
POST mobile-data-2023-11-14/_update_by_query
{
    "script": {
            "id": "update-script",
            "params": {
              "status" : "passed"
            }
        },
        "query": {
            "match": {
              "test_id": "APPTESRqeDGY143KiCDYjD"
            }
    }
}
```

Expected response :

```
{
    "acknowleged" : true
}
```

I got this response :

```
{
  "took" : 59469,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "total" : 1,
  "updated" : 0,
  "deleted" : 0,
  "batches" : 1,
  "version_conflicts" : 0,
  "noops" : 0,
  "retries" : {
    "bulk" : 11,
    "search" : 0
  },
  "throttled_millis" : 0,
  "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
  "failures" : [
    {
      "index" : "mobile-data-2023-11-14",
      "type" : "_doc",
      "id" : "APPTESRqeDGY143KiCDYjD",
      "cause" : {
        "type" : "cluster_block_exception",
        "reason" : "index [mobile-data-2023-11-14] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];"
      },
      "status" : 429
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that: `usage exceeded flood-stage watermark` which means your disks are full. You can remove some indices or you can add more disk spaces.

Check your disk usage with the following API call.

`GET _cat/allocation?v`

Read more about disk watermark: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html#disk-based-shard-allocation

If there are enough disk spaces (default %95 for flood-stage), and you are still getting the same error, run the following API call.

```
PUT _all/_settings
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null
}
```

Comment: It is already false.

Comment: What is the result of the following API call? `GET _cat/allocation?v`. Please add it to your original question.